# Azure Functions "throttling" calls

Tags: azure-functions, timer-trigger

I have an Azure timer Function (v3):

```
    [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Singleton]
    [Function(nameof(FunctionCreateSuspensionRequestsReachSmsLimit))]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 40 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
```

so, it should be called every hour at 40 minutes 0 seconds. But really I see the following:

[image]

Why it's not called at 02:40, 03:40 etc?

Thanks

Comment: Not only 02:40, 03:40; I cannot see the executions at 05:40, 08:40, 09:40, 12:40, 13:40, 15:40, 16:40 and 17:40. Is it true - are you also observed the same?

Comment: I have scheduled the timer trigger at same duration, checking it.

Comment: @HariKrishna of course, I just said for example some of them

Answer (score 0):

I have created .NET 6 Azure Functions Timer Trigger on the Azure Portal with the same duration  `"0 40 * * * *"` you have given:

[image]
Tested today by creating the new function app around 6 AM and checked, it was not missing any schedules in between the executions that I observed for 2 consecutive days:

[image]

[image]

- Even though the log streaming service time outs, schedule functionality works continuously until we stop from the log console.
- Please recreate the Function App Timer Trigger with the same duration and check once.

Comment: all actions did not help :( In any case, thank you for trying to solve my problem and good explanation